# Can we enable AWS Codepipeline for two repositories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, cicd

I have setup CICD through AWS Codepipeline and Code Build that took Bitbucket as a source and deploy my project to ECS Fargate cluster. It is working fine.

Now I have two repositories in bitbucket. One is for frontend, and second is for backend. Now I am very curious that how I can setup CICD for two projects **using only one AWS Codepipeline**. How to make connections with two different repositories? How is it going to work? Is it possible?

Is there any workaround for this? My intention is to deploy frontend and backend of my project using one Codepipeline. How it works with two repositories?

Comment: You can't have to repos. Only one repo can trigger the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently, Codepipeline only accepts 1 and only 1 repository as its source. So there is no built-in solution for your requirement.
2. However, you can do something tricky: Add a CodeBuild build in one of your CodePipeline stages. Within the build container, you can install git and execute `git clone` since you can run any commands in your containers. After that, store the first and second repository codes as artifacts in S3.
3. I am not sure why you prefer 1 pipeline rather than 2, as common practices recommend frontend and backend have their own repository and pipeline for the separation of concerns. But if you insist on it, you can utilize CodeBuild since it is just a container allowing you to execute any commands.

Answer (score 0):

Using below script, I was able to add additional repos as inputs. But i am unable to figure out how to access the output of this prebuild step and copy the python source to s3.

```
const source = CodePipelineSource.gitHub('bharath-t/cdk-project', 'main');
const python_source = CodePipelineSource.gitHub('bharath-t/python-project', 'main');

const prebuild = new ShellStep('Prebuild', {
  input: python_source,
  primaryOutputDirectory: './src',
  commands: ['pip install flake8 pytest build', 'flake8 --exit-zero', 'pytest'],
});

// create pipeline, copy prebuild output into siblingdir within artifacts bucket
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'TestPipeline', {
  pipelineName: 'TestPipeline',
  synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
    input: source,
    additionalInputs: {
      '../siblingdir': prebuild,
    },
    commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth', 'ls -a ../siblingdir'],
  })
});
```